# Scraping a website with PHP

Tags: php, dom, scraper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scrape web page contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584826/scrape-web-page-contents)
>   [How to scrape all content from a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779623/how-to-scrape-all-content-from-a-website)

I'm trying to scrape some boxscore data from the site [covers.com](http://scores.covers.com/college-basketball-scores-matchups.aspx) and for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it.  I want to get boxscores from a certain date but the page defaults to a viewstate of today's games when I use `file_get_html` from the `simplehtmldom` package.  Any ideas on how to get the url for a certain days games?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980519/writing-a-program-to-scrape-forums http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584826/scrape-web-page-contents http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779623/how-to-scrape-all-content-from-a-website and so on

Answer (score 1):

Just loading the HTML page won't help you there. Most of the data is pulled in via AJAX. To find out under which URLs use [`Firebug`](http://www.google.com/search?q=Firebug) or [`Dragonfly`](http://www.google.com/search?q=Dragonfly). Look at the network requests tab, and observe resources and request parameters.

(Obligatory hint that you should have permission to scrape data, unless its for a science and non-commercial purposes.)